# Replicating the background colour on a WPF control

Tags: wpf, styles

I have written a user control which consists of a ListBox and a couple extra controls. I want to wrap the whole thing in a border using the same brush as a standard ListBox would have.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has a page given a standard style for the ListBox, but it has hardcoded colours whereas a standard ListBox uses different styles on different platforms or with different themes. How can I recreate the border of a ListBox in my own control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is to write a function that extracts the default style for a control, and the relevant property from that style:

```
private static TReturn ExtractStyleProperty<TReturn, TFromControl>(string name, TReturn defVal)
{
  var style = Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(TFromControl)) as Style;
  if (style == null){
    return defVal;
  }
  var setter = style.Setters.Where(s => s is Setter).Cast<Setter>().First(s => s.Property.Name.Equals(name));
  if (setter == null){
    return defVal;
  }
  return (TReturn)setter.Value;
}
```

With that I can create a property for each property I want to recreate:

```
public Brush ListBoxBorderBrush {
  get {
    return ExtractStyleProperty<Brush, ListBox>("BorderBrush", new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(130, 135, 144)));
  }
}
```

And then bind my control's properties to those ones. This gets the value appropriate to the system and WPF theme.

Answer (score 2):

I used Microsoft Expression Blend to create a copy of the standard ListBox template. Here's what I got from it...

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="#828790"/>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You should be able to use the same brushes in this default style to get the brushes related to the current theme.

Comment: I get the same template in VS2012

Comment: Isn't that still just hardcoding in the border brush colour (#828790)? That looks fine in Windows 7 using the default theme - but if I change the Windows theme a standard listbox adapts whereas my control and sticks with this border colour.

Comment: I tried three different themes on my computer. My listbox in WPF had the same border color regardless of theme (High contrast, Classic, and my standard theme). I took a screen shot, pasted it into Paint.NET and blew it up to check. As far as WPF goes, it looks like the ListBox border color is the same regardless of theme (Medium grayish)

Comment: @Alan: On Windows 7, I get #828790 on Windows 7 Basic, #808080 on High Contrast #1, High Constrast #2 and High Contrast White, and #b0b0b0 on High Contrast Black.

Comment: That is strange that you got something different and I did not